# Issue with multiple tab Javascript API

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, signalr, dom-events

Our partner provided us with a Javascript API. We call this API based on some events.

For example we receive an event from backend saying save Record XYZ

- Note1: this is an event rather than response of user request.
- Note2: we use signalR for event.

Everything works fine but problem comes when user open two tabs of the same page. Then the same API is called twice and two records are saved instead of one.

This must be one of very typical problem with Javascript and I was hoping there must be some design pattern or solution exist for this?

Comment: If your event is raised from a backend instead of an action the actual user has taken inside of a single tab, why are you using the browser to call the API to save the record? Could you not call the API from the backend?

Comment: Sadly we cant. Our app Actually embed inside the partner’s page. Kind of inside an iframe. So we have javascript API to work with.